# Options to export selective data from one dynamodb table to another table in same region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, migration, amazon-data-pipeline

Need to move data from one dynamodb table to another table after doing a transformation

What is the best approach to do that

Do I need to write a script to read selective data from one table and put in another table

or Do I need to follow CSV export

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a script to do so. However, you may wish to first export the data to S3 using DynamoDB's native function as it does not impact capacity on the table, ensuring you do not impact production traffic for example.

If your table is not serving production traffic or the size of the table is not too large then you can simply use Lambda functions to read your items, transform and then write to the new table.

If your table is large, you can use AWS Glue to achieve the same result in a distributed fashion.

Comment: But I think it's not possible to export selective data , means 100 records out of 1000 records to S3 or is there any way

Comment: No you would need to export all the data, then your ETL job would filter during transform. Be clear that I am only suggesting export if you're reading from a production table and may cause capacity issues for your applications. Otherwise, just write a script.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a live table that is used on prod?

If it is what I usually do is.

- Enable Dynamo streams (if not already enabled)
- Create a lambda function that has access to both tables
- Place transformation logic in the lambda
- Subscribe the lambda to the dynamo stream
- Update all fields on the original table (like update a new field called 'migrate')
- Now all elements will flow through the lambda and it can store them with transformation on the new table
- You can now switch to the new table
- Check if everything still works
- Delete lambda, old table, and disable dynamo streams (if needed)

This approach is the only one I found that can guarantee 100% uptime during the migration.

If the table is not live then you can just export it to S3 and then import it into the new table

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html

Comment: Please do not recommend DataPipeline for imports/exports. Its costly and more complex in comparison to alternative solutions which exist, such as native Import/Export and AWS Glue.

Comment: Will AWS Glue keep the data in sync up until the tables are switched?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But I'm not sure how that relates to my comment?

Comment: Then I will always have a time window where data is lost. If my system is live it constantly updates the data in the original table, if I run the export now and switch to the new table, all data between the export starting and switching to the new table will be lost

Comment: I'm not suggesting not to use streams. I just suggested not to propose DataPipeline as an initial migration as its more costly and complex to alternatives. DP is no longer the de-facto solution.

Comment: For update all the fields I need to know all GSI , then based on that I need to update it , M I  right or is that possible that earlier created data also come in stream @borislav

Comment: No need to update GSIs if the destination table has the exact same keys. It will be as if they were inserted by the application itself

Comment: No , my question is on your point "Update all fields on the original table (like update a new field called 'migrate')" , How I need to do that , whether need to write a script to update all the fields or there is any other alternative @Borislav

Comment: In the approach, I am proposing that is the only way because it relies on Dynamo Streams.

Comment: This approach really depends on how much data you have, as this approach causes you to read and write to the source table which can be expensive. Ideally you only want to read from the source and write to destination.

Comment: Yes if, its a one-time export and you can afford to have some downtime, then your proposal is better